# find and grep or another way?

Tags: grep, find

I am using Linux Mint
I would like to find files less then 90k and search containing text "media" in them.

I have tried;

```
find /directory -size -90k -exec grep -lir --text "media" {} \+
```

This also finds files greater then 90k 
what is the best way of finding only small files containing certain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would restrict the search to files (`-type -f`), then use `xargs` to feed the result list to `grep`, with the `-print0` and `--null` options on both side of the pipe, in case some path contains space:

```
find /directory -type f -size -90k -print0 | xargs --null grep -il --text "media"
```